# Vertical MenuDrawer and ListView scrolling up issue

Tags: android, listview, android-library

I have a problem which I am not sure how can I handle.
I started using a library called MenuDrawer on which I have given the following:

```
    mDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

Which allows it to pop open whenever I drag the screen down, but this actually rises another issue for me, because I use a ListView there that needs to be scrolled also.

I actually have 2 questions, taking in regards that not all may have used this library.

1. If you have used this library: Is it possible to focus the dragging on just 1 element? For example if I have a TextView there can I drag only that item to open the menu?
2. If you haven't used this library: How can a child element steal the focus from the parent on touch event? So that when I touch and drag somewhere where the listview is to achieve a successful scrolling up and down.

Right now I can scroll freely only down and when I try to scroll up opens the menu, unless I scroll the listview first down and up without breaking contact with the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to manage that. For me this simple piece of code worked like a charm:

```
  mDrawer.setOnInterceptMoveEventListener(new OnInterceptMoveEventListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean isViewDraggable(View v, int dx, int x, int y) {
            //v.getId();
            if(y > 50){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }});
```

if anything below Y 50 is pulled it won't trigger the menu drawer.